# Get AWS CLI Documentation programmatically using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, documentation, aws-cli

It there any way to get AWS CLI Documentation programmatically? For Instance, from command line `aws ec2 run-instances help` produces Description/Filters/examples/and Explanation of JSON output.

Is there any API (Java/Python) that fetches the documentation in code?

I tried to see how CLI is able to produce it. I tried to see in `aws-cli` GitHub repo and found a program `awscli/clidocs.py`. Seems it is using `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI` but, I could not progress much!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it looks like the starting url or the base url is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/ and then to this url you can add the service and start scraping the content. For example lets say you wanted to find about ec2 then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/ec2 will give the welcome page about ec2 and then you need to find the next link on the page and get the url and read that next and so forward.

This is the general approach on which the python code is written.